# Widget Quotes, get list quotes from TXT

Tags: android, arraylist, widget

Everyone. Good afternoon.

This is a android widget. I'm using this code. I just wanted to get the ArrayList from a external file as .TXT instead of getting quotes' list from the java file.

This is my code:

```
   public class UpdateWidgetService extends Service {
private static final String TAG = UpdateWidgetService.class.getSimpleName();

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {
    super.onStart(intent, startId);

    Log.d(TAG, "onStart started");

    // Create some random data
    Random random = new Random();

    AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(this.getApplicationContext());

    int[] appWidgetIds = intent.getIntArrayExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_IDS);

    if (appWidgetIds.length > 0) {

        for (int widgetId : appWidgetIds) {
            List<String> qList = getListFromTxtFile("quote.txt");
            int nextInt = random.nextInt(qList.size());

            RemoteViews remoteViews = new RemoteViews(getPackageName(), R.layout.widget);
            remoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.widget_textview, qList.get(nextInt));
            appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(widgetId, remoteViews);
        }
        stopSelf();
    }
    super.onStart(intent, startId);
}

public List<String> getListFromTxtFile(String txtFileName){

//  File sdcard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
// Get the text file
// File file = new File(sdcard,txtFileName);

AssetManager am = this.getAssets();

List<String> qList = new ArrayList<String>();

//Read text from file

try {
    InputStream is = am.open("quote.txt");
          //BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
    String line;

     // get data in text file line by line
    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {

       qList.add(line);
    }
}
catch (IOException e) {
    //You'll need to add proper error handling here
}
return qList;

}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this method to read text file from Assets and return list

```
public List<String> getListFromTxtFile(String txtFileName){

//  File sdcard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
// Get the text file
// File file = new File(sdcard,txtFileName);

AssetManager am = this.getAssets();

List<String> qList = new ArrayList<String>();

//Read text from file

try {
    InputStream is = am.open(txtFileName);
          //BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
    String line;

     // get data in text file line by line
    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {

       qList.add(line);
    }
}
catch (IOException e) {
    //You'll need to add proper error handling here
}
return qList;
```

}

Comment: Ok, where I put my "txtFile"? In Assets?

Comment: in SDcard root directory.   If you want put it in Assests folder let me know to edit my answer to achieve what you want.

Comment: Yeah, I would like to put my file in Assests folder :)

Comment: There is something wrong in this line:

    List<String> qList = getQuotes();

Comment: My method name is `getListFromTxtFile()` or are you change it?? and what is the wrong??

Comment: I didn't change your method name. But the code says "List<String> qList = getQuotes();" is not correct. There is a red mark under it. I think there is a conflic between that code with getListFromTxtFile() method.... :/ But I don't know. I'm a newbie!!!

Comment: And my txtFileName is "quote" - quote.txt

Comment: Change this `List<String> qList = getQuotes();` to `List<String> qList = getListFromTxtFile("quote.txt");`

Comment: Alright. I did it! It's OK. But the widget isn't reading the "quote.txt".... App/Widget doesn't work now

Comment: I edited it. See it, AwadKab.....what is the wrong now??? The "quote.txt" is in "assets folder"

Comment: You called `super.onStart(intent, startId);` two times in `onStart(...)`